# Showing all the decimal numbers on the y axis clearly in a given chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, charts

I would like to show my y axis as follows:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar=1.2pt,% configures `bar shift'
    width=0.80*\textwidth,
    height=7cm,
    ymin=0,
    bar width=10pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.07,
    symbolic x coords={system,system2,system3,system4,system5,system6,system7,system8,system9,system10},
    grid style={dotted,gray},
    tick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    xtick=data,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    ytick={0,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000},
    point meta=y,
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east,tickwidth=2mm,
                        at={(xticklabel cs:0.9,5pt)}, xticklabel},
    legend columns=1,
    legend style={draw=none,nodes={inner sep=2pt}}
]
\addplot[pattern=horizontal lines light blue,pattern color=orange] coordinates 
{(system,62692) (system2,51132) (system3,21046)(system4,11902) (system5,3740) (system6,5898)(system7,3870) (system8,1383) (system9,3947) (system10,849)};
\legend{VS}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, my chart now shows the y axis with point meta (e.g., 10^4). 
How can I disable it? Even though, I do not use a specific property, the chart automatically adjusts the y axis by itself as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable this behavior by the option `scaled y ticks = false`.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    ybar=1.2pt, % configures `bar shift'
    width=0.80*\textwidth,
    height=7cm,
    ymin=0,
    bar width=10pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.07,
    symbolic x coords={system,system2,system3,system4,system5,system6,system7,system8,system9,system10},
    grid style={dotted,gray},
    tick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    xtick=data,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    ytick={0,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000},
    point meta=y,
    x tick label style={%
            ,rotate=90
            ,anchor=east
            ,tickwidth=2mm
            ,at={(xticklabel cs:0.9,5pt)}
            ,xticklabel
            },
    legend columns=1,
    legend style={draw=none,nodes={inner sep=2pt}},
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    scaled y ticks = false 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
]
\addplot[%
    ,pattern=horizontal lines light blue
    ,pattern color=orange
    ] coordinates 
{(system,62692) (system2,51132) (system3,21046)(system4,11902) (system5,3740) (system6,5898)(system7,3870) (system8,1383) (system9,3947) (system10,849)};
\legend{VS}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you run into further problems (maybe for other values on your y axis), you may want to add `y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}` as well. This is recommended but does not show any effect in your example.